# Wait for response from HttpClient get - synchronous call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am wondering how to wait for the response from an HttpClient action that is calling a backend, my need is to wait until the backend returns gives response (synchronous call), the classic approach is to subscribe to the Observable response :

```
//My component
...
console.log("before");
this.myService.getSomeThingFromBackend('param_value').subscribe(response => {
     console.log("do my stuff");
}
console.log("after");

//My Service
...
getSomeThingFromBackend(param: string): Observable<any>{
        return this.httpClient.get(this.host + this.url+ "/" + param);
}
```

this shows :

```
before

after

do my stuff
```

And I want this result :

```
before

do my stuff

after
```

Comment: Just put `console.log("after")` inside the subscribe since it's an asynchronous process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's `this.http.get` returns an **RxJS Observable**. Then calling `this.http.get(...).subscribe(...)` returns RxJS `Subscription` object. So none of them return Promise so you can't use them with `await`.

If you want to be able to use `await` with Observables you have to use `toPromise()` instead of `subscribe()` that returns a Promise that is resolved with the first value emitted by that Observable (it internally calles `subscribe` for you and wraps it with a Promise object).

```
await this.http.get(...).toPromise(value => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: I see so many people suggesting that observable problems can be solved by converting them to promises. No! It just means the observables are being used incorrectly. Using promises means you lose out on a lot of the power of RxJS.

Comment: @KurtHamilton my need is to do the call synchronously, any way thank you for the clarification, which is 100% correct

Comment: @Sanjay Lohar I will just add that the promise should be handeled with then() end catch() methods

Comment: yeah give a proper syntax so that others can get a standard way to use this.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi question edited, I think it is clear enough

Comment: `toPromise()` has changed, see https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Answer (score 2):

You might not want to use HttpClient in this scenario.
Use **synchronous** http request as below

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', "https://domain/api", false);  
request.send(null);
const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Would not be able to take advantage of DI using `HttpClient` and hence should be used absolutely when required.

Answer (score 1):

As the risk of sounding obvious... if you want to perform one action after another, then move the action that is in the wrong place.

```js
//My component
...
console.log("before");
this.myService.getSomeThingFromBackend('param_value').subscribe(response => {
  console.log("do my stuff");
  console.log("after");
}

//My Service
...
getSomeThingFromBackend(param: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.host + this.url+ "/" + param);
}
```

Everything else you are doing is sound. You are returning the observable from the service, subscribing to it in the component, and running an action in the subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

This process works asynchronously, so you can not keep it waiting for the other stuff until they are in the response scope. You can write those call in the same scope or make a function and call it from the inside.

```
//My component

...
console.log("before");
this.myService.getSomeThingFromBackend('param_value').subscribe(response => {
     console.log("do my stuff");
     doSomeStuff();
}

doSomeStuff(){
    console.log("after");
}

//My Service
...
getSomeThingFromBackend(param: string): Observable<any>{
        return this.httpClient.get(this.host + this.url+ "/" + param);
}
```